# Mod_rewrite working on localhost, but not on GoDaddy shared hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically, I am trying to clean up my URLs to remove file extensions.

For example, I have a file named `contact.php`. I want to display this page in the browser, but I want my URL to look as follows:

```
https://www.example.com/contact/
```

I also want links on my site to display the cleaned-up version, so in my HTML I link to this page link this:

```
<a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a>
```

The mod_rewrite rules I have in my .htaccess are working perfectly on localhost, but when pushed to a testing subdomain on my GoDaddy shared hosting server, I get a "too many redirects" error. The .htaccess file is located in the subfolder for this subdomain.

Here is my entire .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# custom 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# always remove index.ext
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html)$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.(php|html)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# redirect somepage.ext to /somepage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^/?(.*).(php|html)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# always make sure page has trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I should mention that all of the other statements are working on the live server (404 page, remove index.ext, and training slash). I'm only facing the issue with the URL rewrite.

Comment: Have a try disabling the `MultiViews` option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added `Options -MultiViews` to the top of my .htaccess file, but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try above code in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```